# get text value inside the shape where line arrow started (excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Please see this image]

Hi, I am still learning VBA. I need help on the above. Say, the square shapes are msoAutoShape. I need a code that will loop through all the said shapetype and get the text inside the shape where the line arrow started and where it ended.

The expected output:

Started on "test1" and ended on "test2",
Started on "test3" and ended on "test4",

maybe just put it in msgbox. Any simple sample code will do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the `Shape.TopLeftCell` and `Shape.BottomRightCell` properties to and `Intersect()` function to identify the shapes.  If you run into any problems comeback and post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next way. The code firstly identify the arrow connector type shapes, extract its left and right cell range and call a function which returns the necessary text strings, if intersections have been found:

```
Sub testIterateConnectorsArrow()
    Dim shC As Shape, rngCLeft As Range, rngCRight As Range, arrTxt
     For Each shC In ActiveSheet.Shapes 'iterate between all shapes in the active sheet
        'identify all shapes being of type arrow conectors from left to right:
        If shC.AutoShapeType = -2 And shC.ShapeStyle = 10003 Then
            'set the ranges from left, respectivele right for each arrow connector:
            Set rngCLeft = shC.TopLeftCell: Set rngCRight = shC.BottomRightCell
            arrTxt = extractRectanglesText(rngCLeft, rngCRight) 'extract the necessary text
            MsgBox "Left text: " & arrTxt(0) & vbCrLf & _
                   "Right text: " & arrTxt(1)
        End If
     Next
End Sub

Function extractRectanglesText(rLeft As Range, rRight As Range) As Variant 'it returns an array with both found strings
   Dim shR As Shape, rngRect As Range, sh As Shape, leftSh As Shape, rightSh As Shape
   For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes  'iterate between all shapes in the active sheet
       If sh.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then                        'in case of a rectangle:
            Set rngRect = Range(sh.TopLeftCell, sh.BottomRightCell)        'create the range covered by the shape
            If Not Intersect(rLeft, rngRect) Is Nothing Then Set leftSh = sh   'checking the intersection with the left line side
            If Not Intersect(rRight, rngRect) Is Nothing Then Set rightSh = sh 'checking the intersection with the right line side
            If Not leftSh Is Nothing And Not rightSh Is Nothing Then Exit For 'if both shapes found, exit the iteration
       End If
   Next
   If Not leftSh Is Nothing And Not rightSh Is Nothing Then 'returning only if both line terminations intersect ranges:
        extractRectanglesText = Array(leftSh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, rightSh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text)
   End If
End Function
```

The function can be adapted to return even if only one intersection (left/right) exists...